# How to declare a variable which accept both Number/Date

Tags: sql-server, ssrs-2008, ssms

In my table, the field "No & Date" accepts both No & Date, could you tell me how to declare this variable?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you really must mix data types what about SQL Variant?
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms173829.aspx

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, it's probably best to use a `varchar` datatype to store both numbers and date. That way, you can explicitly convert `varchar` to `date` datatype. Also, SQL Server implicitly converts `varchar` to `int`. Please refer to the chart below from Microsoft:

[image: SQL Server Data Type Conversion Chart]